# Failed to start gitlab-runner register on CentOS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed gitlab-runner on CentOS machine, but on register step it fails with "**connection refused**":

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "https://%myGitlab%/" --registration-token "%myToken%" --executor "shell" --description "TestServerRunner" --tag-list "TestRunner, CIOnTest"
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=3149 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Running in system-mode.

ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=yoqL_Qsh status=couldn't execute POST against https://%myGitlab%/api/v4/runners: Post https://%myGitlab%/api/v4/runners: dial tcp %myGitlabIp%:443: connect: **connection refused**
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

However, if i try to connect to gitlab.com it prints out normal 'error' - wrong token:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "https://gitlab.com/" --registration-token "%myToken%" --executor "shell" --description "TestServerRunner" --tag-list "TestRunner, CIOnTest"
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=8259 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Running in system-mode.

ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token)  runner=yoqL_Qsh
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

What may be wrong? Ping to %MyGitlabIp% exists.

Comment: Just a side note, CentOS will reach EOL [this year](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/); if that means you'll have to migrate anyway, maybe you'll want to see if the issue persists on whatever distro you decided to migrate to. [There is a centOS fork that continues it and has nice migration scripts](https://rockylinux.org/).

Comment: This is going to be a network-related error with the connection between your runner machine and your gitlab instance. While pinging the instance may work properly, ICMP (ping) traffic uses different ports and protocols from HTTPS traffic. If you try to run `curl https://<my instance domain>` from your box, you will probably get an error. You should check your firewall rules on your self-hosted gitlab instance.

Comment: Tahnks @Patrick, though I understand it already. Problem was in firewall rules on target gitlab machine. If you post your comment as answer I will check It as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a network-related error with the connection between your runner machine and your gitlab instance. While pinging the instance may work properly, ICMP (ping) traffic uses different ports and protocols from HTTPS traffic. If you try to run `curl https://<my instance domain>` from your box, you will probably get an error. You should check your firewall rules on your self-hosted gitlab instance.

It sounds like this was resolved by opening up a firewall rule on the machine running the self-hosted gitlab instance.